# input date html5

Tags: html5

Estive procurando por configurações do html5 para o atributo date exibir a data no formato que utilizamos no Brasil(dd/mm/aaaa), mas parece que não tem nenhuma configuração extra para isso. Em alguns tutoriais o formato padrão já é este, mas o meu calendário é exibido no padrão yyyy/mm/dd. Alguma solução para isto?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body oncontextmenu='return false' onselectstart='return false' ondragstart='return false'>  <!-- Não deixa o usuário clicar com o botão direito na página -->
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <?php
            include "header.php";
        ?>
            <div class="conteudo_painel">
                <h1>Painel do Cliente - <?php echo $_SESSION['nome_cliente']; ?></h1> <!-- Nome do cliente para mostrar no painel -->
                <!-- Div sobre o boleto -->
                    <div class="segunda_via">
                        <h2>2ª via do boleto</h2>
                        <h4>Escolha a data que efetuará o pagamento:</h4>
                        <form method="post" action="?acao=confirmar">
                            </br><input type="date" id="data" name="data" maxlength="10" size="" OnKeyPress=" formatar('##/##/####', this)">
                            </br><input type="image" src="img/gera_boleto.png" value="Confirmar" id="gera_boleto">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        } else { //caso o boleto não tenha vencido e o cliente não tenha pago, mostra o boleto primeira via
                    ?>
                        <div class="boleto_itau" >
...
```

[image: O chrome exibe no formato br e o safari no norte americado]

Comment: Dá uma lida aqui
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: Tentei aqui tá em no padrão brasileiro mesmo. Dê uma olhada aqui. http://jsfiddle.net/Ls8gxzk7/

Comment: Olá, Tente dessa forma, utilizando a biblioteca do jQuery UI: Exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/uLnrd6pu/

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
```

Segue um exemplo utilizando o datepicker pt-br, onde o mesmo está disponível em: [link github jquery.ui.datepicker-pt-BR.js](https://github.com/jquery/codeorigin.jquery.com/blob/master/cdn/ui/1.8.8/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-pt-BR.js)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>teste</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="datepicker-pt-BR.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Data: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nos meus testes aqui, nos navegadores `webkit` (Chrome, Safari, Maxthon e afins) o formato da data corresponde ao formato definido no sistema operacional e mesmo colocando o atributo `lang="pt-BR"` (tentei nas tags `<html>`, `<body>` e no próprio `<input>`) o formato não respeitou o padrão brasileiro. No Firefox e IE (11) o `input[type=date]` se comporta como um input de texto normal.

Comment: Utilizo o safari pra testar a visualização do ipad e iphone, nele o formato é em inglês, mas no chrome é em português. Deve ser alguma configuração do webkit dele então...

Comment: Talvez seria interessante você ver um componente datepicker do jqueryui portugues.

Comment: * Configurar em português o componente datepicker do jqueryui.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
<br><br>
<center>
<p>Digite a data:<br />
    <input type="text" data-format="00/00/0000"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
    <script>
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("input[data-format]");
inputElements.forEach(input => {
    let m = new IMask(input, {
        mask: input.getAttribute("data-format")
    });
});
</script>
</center>
</html>
```

Você pode usar apenas o input que fica mais simples.